# mongodb on windows 10 without windows server 2008?

Tags: mongodb

I'd like to install MongoDB Community Edition on my computer, which has the 64-bit Windows 10 Home OS, but the system requirements say I need Windows Server 2008 to do it.

I don't think my computer has Windows Server 2008. Is there any way around this? For example, would it work for small-scale databases, or is it totally incompatible without Windows Server 2008?

If I absolutely can't use MongoDB, is there another **non**-relational database that would work with my system? (It would have to be free.)

Answer (score 0):

I admit that the download site is a bit confusing.
But you can simply download the MSI and install it on your Windows 10 machine. A Windows Server version is not required for the community edition.

Disclaimer: I have it on a Pro (Windows 7 and 10, without Windows 2008 or any other server) edition, not on a Home edition, but I'm pretty sure that it will work in the local machine context)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but do you have Windows Server 2008 on your system? I agree that Home vs. Pro likely wouldn't make a difference. The question is really whether Server is needed or not, or what alternatives are out there.

Comment: I use Windows 7 and 10 with the community edition. Updated/clarified my answer.

Comment: Yes, but you are not telling me whether you have Server 2008 or something similar on your system. I wasn't asking about the operating system. I know Windows 10 meets the requirement for the OS.

Comment: I have MongoDB Community Server installed in Windows 10 without Server 2008: https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=nav#community Works perfectly.

Comment: Correct. Windows 2008 is not on my machine and it would not play a role while running an OS like Windows 7 or 10.